# Let AVPlayer continue playing when pressing the 'back' button on the UINavigation Controller in Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, avplayer

I’m developing a Radio Streaming app, it streams OK. Also it plays in background when press on the ‘Home’ button and ‘lock’ button.

The application is embedded into a `UINavigationController` and when I press on the ‘back’ button in the UINavigationController it stops playing. 
My question is: How do I let the `UIViewController` that contain the `AVPlayer` to remain active when pressing the ‘back’ button in the navigation controller so that the `AVPlayer` continue streaming?

My code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import Foundation

class RadioFunctionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!
var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
private let ObservatingKeyPath = "currentItem.status"
private let PlayerStatusObservingContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 1)
private var playingState:Bool = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setStatus(4)
    getAudioData("http://184.107.179.162:7546/;")
    playingState = true


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    toggle()
}

func getAudioData(audioURL:String)
{
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioURL)!)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: nil)
}

func setStatus(rawValue:Int)
{
    if rawValue == 1
    {
        statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        statusLabel.text = "Ready for Streaming"
    }else if rawValue == 2
    {
        statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        statusLabel.text = "Failed"

    }else if rawValue == 0
    {
        statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        statusLabel.text = "Failed to load data"
    }else if rawValue == 3
    {
        statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        statusLabel.text = "Streaming"
    }else if rawValue == 4
    {
        statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        statusLabel.text = "Gather data..."
    }
    print("The raw value send is: \(rawValue)")
}

func audioBackgroundPlayback()
{
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }catch {
        print("Could not play audio in the background")
    }

    if (NSClassFromString("MPNowPlayingInfoCenter") != nil)
    {
        let artWorkImage = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(named: "ws")!)
        let songInfo2: [String:  AnyObject] = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Wide Streamings ABC Edition", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Rumbera Network", MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: "107.9 FM", MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artWorkImage]

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo2
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    }


}

func toggle()
{
    if playButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play"
    {
        print("The play option is chosen")
        playRadio()
    }else{
        print("The pause option is chosen")
        pauseRadio()
    }
}

func playRadio()
{
    player.play()
    setStatus(3)
    playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    audioBackgroundPlayback()
}

func pauseRadio()
{
    player.pause()
    playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
    if event?.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl
    {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay
        {
            toggle()
        }else if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause
        {
            pauseRadio()
        }else if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause
        {
            toggle()
        }
    }
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    if (keyPath!.containsString("status"))
    {
        if player.status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay
        {
            player.prerollAtRate(0.001, completionHandler: {(succes:Bool)-> Void in

                if succes{
                    self.setStatus(1)
                    self.setStatus(3)
                    self.playRadio()

                }else{
                    self.setStatus(1)
                    self.setStatus(2)
                }

            })
        }else if player.status == AVPlayerStatus.Failed{
            self.setStatus(2)

        }else if player.status == AVPlayerStatus.Unknown
        {
            self.setStatus(0)
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    if playingState == true
    {
        audioBackgroundPlayback()
        player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
        print("The AVPlayer is playing in background")
    }else{
        player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
        print("The view Dissapear")
    }


}
```

Hope someone could help me out with this one
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to fix it by doing some modification to the AppDelegate Class.

The modification into the AppDelegate:

```
var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
internal var avPlayerUpdateNotification = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let notificationStateupdate = "RadioStationChangeUpdate"
let radioStationChangeNSString:NSString = "RadioStationChangeNotification"
private var isPlaying:Bool = false
private var selectedRadioStation:String = ""

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setNewSelectedRadioStation:", name: radioStationChangeNSString as String, object: nil)

    return true
}
```

Other functions that has been added into the AppDelegate Class

```
func streamAudio(audioLink:String)
{
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioLink)!)
    player.play()
    isPlaying = true
}

func play()
{
    player.play()
    isPlaying = true
}

func pause()
{
    player.pause()
    isPlaying = false
}

func getPlayerState() -> Bool
{
    return isPlaying
}

func setCurrentSelectedRadioStation(selectedStation:String)
{
    self.selectedRadioStation = selectedStation
}

func getCurrentSelectedRadioStation() -> String
{
    return selectedRadioStation
}

func setNewSelectedRadioStation(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let radioStation = notification.object!

    if (radioStation.containsString("Rumbera network"))
    {
        if(selectedRadioStation == radioStation as! String)
        {
            print("Rumbera Network is already playing")
        }else{
            print("Rumbera Network is selected in AppDelegate")
            streamAudio("http://184.107.179.162:7546/;")
            setCurrentSelectedRadioStation(radioStation as! String)
        }
    }else if (radioStation.containsString("RocKorsow"))
    {
        if(selectedRadioStation == radioStation as! String)
        {
            print("RocKorsow is already playing")
        }else{
            print("RocKorsow is selected in AppDelegate")
            streamAudio("http://youngfreshfast.serverroom.us:9166")
            setCurrentSelectedRadioStation(radioStation as! String)
        }
    }else if (radioStation.containsString("Pause"))
    {
        pause()
    }else if (radioStation.containsString("Play"))
    {
        play()
    }else{
        print("Nothing is found")
    }

}
```

The class that handles the AVPlayer:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import Foundation

class RadioFunctionViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
private let ObservatingKeyPath = "currentItem.status"
private let PlayerStatusObservingContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 1)
private var playingState:Bool = false
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkPlayerCurrentState()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func performAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    let buttonLabel = (sender.titleLabel?.text)!

    switch buttonLabel
    {
        case "Play":
        print("The AVPlayer is playing")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RadioStationChangeNotification", object: NSString(string: "Play"))
        playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        case "Pause":
        print("The AVPlayer is pause")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RadioStationChangeNotification", object: NSString(string: "Pause"))
        playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    default:
        break

    }
}

func checkPlayerCurrentState()
{
    let player_state = getPlayerState()
    if player_state == true
    {
        print("The AVPlayer is playing")
        playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else{
        print("The AVPlayer is not playing")
        playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}

func getPlayerState() -> Bool
{
    let state = appDelegate.getPlayerState()
    return state
}

func audioBackgroundPlayback()
{
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }catch {
        print("Could not play audio in the background")
    }
}
```

Hope my solution could help someone that encounter the same problem.
Thanks guys for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

`AVPlayer` will continue to work as long as it is active. Once the referencing `UIViewController` is released by popping back `AVPlayer` will also be discarded from memory.

I would advise you to create a singleton player class and create APIs to start/stop/play/pause `AVPlayer` in that. Now, you can access it globally from everywhere in your app.

**EDIT:** For OP convenience (a sample to start with):

```
class MyAVPlayer {
    static let sharedInstance = MyAVPlayer()

    var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()

    func play() {
        // Put play code here
    }

    func playWithURL(url : NSURL) {
        // Put play code here
    }
}
```

Call it like (from anywhere in your application):

```
MyAVPlayer.sharedInstance.playWithURL(myURL)
```

Comment: Thanks Abhinav for your quick respond. I'm going to try to implement a singleton class since I'm new to this programming Language.

Comment: Always happy to help :)! implementing singleton is a fairly simple task. You may refer to [this blog](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/) once.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the singleton class still no positive respond.

Comment: I've added a sample to start with. You can add code based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav for your respond. I manage to fix by modify the AppDelegate Class and it works fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the player is Embed in your controller

```
var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

So when you press the back button, the controller is popped and deallocated and your player with it.
What you have to do is to put the player property elsewhere (AppDelegate, Custom navigation controller for exemple) to keep a reference on it that'll keep it alive.

Comment: Or you can make some singleton like `AudioPlayerProvider`      `class AudioPlayerProvider {
      static let sharedProvider = AudioPlayerProvider()
      ...
    }`

Comment: It's also a solution. But If I can, I avoid Singleton, it's a personal choice :).

Comment: @KIDdAe: I'm trying to implement the AVPlayer function into the AppDelegate class. I will post the results as soon as I finish with my solution.